# Nuget package description in the Azure DevOps Nuget pipeline step

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to add a description for the NuGet package being added in the Azure DevOps Pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nuget package description in the Azure DevOps Nuget pipeline step

As we know, when we pack the nuget package with `.csproj` file, nuget will get the package info from the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the project, like `assembly: AssemblyVersion`, `assembly: AssemblyDescription` and so on.

So, to add a description for the NuGet package, we could add the description for `assembly: AssemblyDescription` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("This is Test Decription!!!")]
```

Then push this update in to the Azure DevOps repos, in this case, we could pack the package with that description.

Besides, if you want use the `.nuspec` file, we need create this file on local machine with the command line `nuget spec "..\*.csproj"`, then modify the `<description>$description$</description>` in the `.nuspec`, upload this file to the repos.

Check the document [Creating NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) to create the `.nuspec` file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Expand the "Advanced", then in the "Additional build properties" specify the value you want in this way:

```
Description="value"
```

[image]

It works **only** if you pack a `.nuspec` file or `.csproj` & check-in/push the `.nuspec`, and in the nuspec there is token for this:

```
<description>$description$</description>
```

**EDIT:**

According to your comment you pack the `.csproj` file, so you need to create the `.nuspec` file.

How? go to the `.csproj` folder and open there CMD, run the following command:

```
nuget spec
```

Now commit & push (or check-in) the file.

Of course, you can open the `.nuspec` and edit the `<description>` section and then commit & push and to your NuGet package will be description or edit the AssemblyInfo, but if you want to do it during the build you can do it with my example above.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually packing a .csproj . Is there a way to generate the nuspec file for it? I cannot find it int the solution

Comment: Go to `.csprog` folder and run there `nuget spec`, then commit & push.