# NuGet pack not using properties in Azure Pipelines build task

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a project and repo in Azure DevOps called `MyProject`. In the build pipeline for this I'm trying to pack and push a NuGet, but I want the name changed to `MyCompany.MyProject`.

I've added `Id` (and `Description`) to the properties in the azure-pipelines.yml command as follows:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: nugetVersion
    buildProperties: 'Id=MyCompany.MyProject;Description=Test'
```

And while these are included in the `-Properties` to the `nuget pack` command (see below), they don't get used. My NuGet name remains `MyProject` only, and also note in the following output from the `NuGetCommand@2` task, that it says `WARNING: NU5115: Description was not specified`.

```
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.2.0\x64\nuget.exe pack d:\a\1\s\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory d:\a\1\a -Properties Configuration=Release;Id=MyCompany.MyProject;Description=Test -version 1.1.9 -Verbosity Detailed
NuGet Version: 5.2.0.6090
Attempting to build package from 'MyProject.csproj'.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.200.19.32702' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
Packing files from 'd:\a\1\s\MyProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1'.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Add file 'd:\a\1\s\MyProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.dll' to package as 'lib\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.dll'
WARNING: NU5115: Description was not specified. Using 'Description'.
```

It seems like the command is using some other source for these properties. Can I change this?

Some posts seemed to say that the *.csproj is used. I tried setting the fields in the project `Properties>Package` in VS2017 to my desired values, but it didn't help.

**EDIT:**
I don't have a `AssemblyInfo.cs` or a `.nuspec`, and prefer not to add. So I don't agree that this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426006/nuget-package-description-in-the-azure-devops-nuget-pipeline-step). zivkan's suggestion to use `dotnet pack` instead of `nuget pack` led to a solution without having to add either of those.

Comment: Perhaps you need quotes around the property values? For example: `Description="Test"`

Comment: NuGetCommand runs nuget.exe, and nuget.exe pack is really only good for packages.config projects. If you're using PackageReference (all SDK style projects do, so all .net core and .net standard), you should use dotnet pack instead.

Comment: Thanks zivkan! That helped. I edited the project Properties>Package and then used DotNetCoreCLI instead of NuGetCommand in the pipeline, and it worked.